# Weird read/write time for attachments while using javamail

Tags: java, io, jakarta-mail

I've been sitting with this for a while now. I have a following code snippet which is intended to create an eml file.

```
private void saveAsEml(Message msg){

    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("path-to-file.eml"))) {
        msg.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

But if the `Message msg` has a slightly bigger attachment (10mb csv file), these two lines block for 10-15 minutes.

What is the problem here? I know that `InputStream` inside the message is very long and reading through may take some time, but I don't understand the core. I've managed to find examples where people are reading through 200MB file within 250ms.

Thank you, 
Bob.

Comment: Try it with a BufferedOutputStream around the FileOutputStream.

Comment: The issue is still there after this suggestion :(

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `Message` coming from? If you retrieved it from a mailbox using IMAP, the attachments might haven't been downloaded yet. When you write that message to the local file system all these parts have to be downloaded from the mail server and if that connection is very slow you end up with the long times you see.